# CSS style cannot be set dynamically (Cell color)

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to achieve requirement to give status on the basis of two parameters. I am able to achieve latest status but not able to achieve cell color.

Scenarios :

```
Scenario #       a           b         Final Status
----------   ---------   ---------   -----------------
    1)       ""(Blank)   ""(Blank)   ""(Blank)
    2)       "Y"         ""(Blank)   "Y"
    3)       "N"         ""(Blank)   "Y"
    4)       ""(Blank)   "Y"         "Y"(Yellow color)
    5)       ""(Blank)   "N"         "N"(Yellow color)
    6)       "Y"         "Y"         "Y"
    7)       "N"         "N"         "N"
    8)       "N"         "Y"         "Y"(Yellow color)
    9)       "Y"         "N"         "Y"(Yellow color)
```

XML code:

```
<Text id="idStatus" text="{parts :['parameter','parameter1'],
    formatter: '.formatter.availableColor'}"></Text>
```

Formatter js :

```
availableColor: function(available, available1) {
                var that = this;
                var idText = that.getView().byId("idStatus");
                idText.removeStyleClass("yellow");

                if (available === "" && available1 === "Y") {

                    idText.addStyleClass("yellow");
                    return "Keep";
                } else if (available === "Y" && available1 === "Y") {
                    return "Keep";

                } else if (available === "N" && available1 === "Y") {
                    idText.addStyleClass("yellow");
                    return "Keep";
                } else if (available === "Y" && available1 === "") {
                    return "Keep";
                } else if (available === "" && available1 === "") {
                    return available;
                } else if (available === "" && available1 === "N") {
                    idText.addStyleClass("yellow");
                    return "Remove";
                } else if (available === "N" && available1 === "N") {

                    return "Remove";
                } else if (available === "Y" && available1 === "N") {
                    idText.addStyleClass("yellow");
                    return "Remove";
                } else if (available === "N" && available1 === "") {
                    return "Remove";
                }


            }

        };
```

CSS style sheet:

```
.yellow {
    background-color: #FFFF66 !important;
}
```

Json data :

```
{
    "parameter": "",
    "parameter1": "Y",
}
```

Comment: I am using - sap.m table

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically add CSS classes/ change the colour of things like cells etc the best solution I have generally found is using custom data.

I wrote about this sort of thing in my blog https://www.nathanhand.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-add-dynamic-css-using-databinding-in-sapui5

But to save a click, you could do something like the below:

```html
<Text id="idStatus" text="{parts :['parameter','parameter1'],formatter: '.formatter.availableColor'}">
    <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="colour" value="{parameter}{parameter1}" writeToDom="true" />
    </customData>
</Text>
```

Which would leave you with something like `data-colour="YN"`

And then with your CSS you could add in:

```css
[data-colour="YN"]{
    background-color: #FFFF66 !important;
}
```

Comment: You've done the correct thing here by including the relevant information from your blog post into your answer.  I would just caution you on doing this too much.  Even though you are following the rules too much self promotion can also be considered spam.  For details, see: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: Hi Nathan,Thanks for your help but it didn't help. I am still not able to get the right color on the right text as mentioned in the scenario.

Comment: @Oyo What results do you get? with the custom data, you should see the results of the binding in the DOM and as such, you can see what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround, if anyone has the better solution kindly share.

**view.js**

```
<Table items="{/items}" updateFinished="afterDataBinding">      
  <columns>
    <Column> <Text text="Amount" /> </Column>
    <Column> <Text text="Quantity" /> </Column>
    <Column> <Text text="Weight" /> </Column>
    <Column> <Text text="Status" /> </Column>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <cells>
        <Text text="{Amount}" />
        <Text text="{Quantity}" />
        <Text text="{Unit}" />
        <Text text="{parts: ['parameter', 'parameter1'], formatter:'assets.util.mFormatter.formatTableCell'}" class="statusCell"></Text>                    
      </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
</Table>
```

**controller.js**

```
afterDataBinding: function(oEvent) {
  $("td:has(span.tableCellYellow)").addClass("yellowCell");
},
```

**formatter.js**

```
formatTableCell: function (available, available1) { 
    var oText = this, 
        sReturnValue = "";
    if ((available === "" && available1 === "")  ||
        (available === "Y" && available1 === "Y") ||
        (available === "N" && available1 === "N") ) {
        if (oText.hasStyleClass("tableCellYellow") ){
            oText.removeStyleClass("tableCellYellow");
        }
    } else if ( 
        (available === "" && available1 === "Y") ||
        (available === "Y" && available1 === "") ||
        (available === "N" && available1 === "") ||
        (available === "" && available1 === "Y") ||
        (available === "" && available1 === "N") ||
        (available === "Y" && available1 === "N") ||
        (available === "N" && available1 === "Y")) {
        if (!oText.hasStyleClass("tableCellYellow") ){
            oText.addStyleClass("tableCellYellow");
        }
        sReturnValue = available + " - " + available1;
    }
    return  sReturnValue;
},
```

**CSS**

```
.yellowCell {
    background-color: #FFFF66 !important;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you consider following Fiori design guidelines / best practices, take a look at https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table. There, it also states:

> For status information, use ***[semantic colors](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/colors/#semantic-colors)***.

Instead of coloring the whole cell with custom CSS, try using controls that support semantic colors, for example, [`sap.m.ObjectStatus` (Demo Kit sample)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ObjectStatus/preview).

Here is a demo that showcases the table according to the rule set: **https://embed.plnkr.co/02iC6S0ffMG6xwXM**

[image: sapui5 openui5 table cell color yellow]